# Ошибка в функции на старом PHP

Tags: php

При выполнении на php 4.4.9 выдаёт unepected t_object_operator. В 5-й версии работает. Как подправить для старой версии? Указал место ошибки

```
function get_head_url ($get_content) {

    if (get_url_encoding ($get_content) == "utf-8") $get_content = mb_convert_encoding ($get_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");

    $doc = new DOMDocument ('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    @$doc->loadHTML (strtolower ($get_content));

    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; // <----------------- ошибка тут
    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++) {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);

        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description') {
           $description = trim ($meta->getAttribute('content'));
        }

        if ($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords') {
           $keywords = trim ($meta->getAttribute('content'));
        }
    }

    if (!isset ($title) OR $title == ""){
        $res['0'] = '<i>Не найдено название в метатегах</i>';
    } else {
        $res['0'] = $title;
    }

    if (!isset ($description) OR $description == "") {
        $res['1'] = '<i>Не найдено описание в метатегах</i>';
    } else {
        $res['1'] = str_replace (",", ", ", $description);
    }

    if (!isset ($keywords) OR $keywords == "") {
        $res['2'] = false;
    } else {
        $res['2'] = str_replace (",", ", ", $keywords);
    }

    return $res;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PHP 4 цепочки вызовов не работают.
замените

```
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

на

```
$item  = $nodes->item(0);
$title = $item->nodeValue;
```